# What does the V in vpath stand for?

Tags: makefile, vpath

The `VPATH` variable in makefile is used to indicate search paths. But what exactly does the "V" in it stand for?

> The value of the make variable VPATH specifies a list of directories that make should search. Most often, the directories are expected to contain prerequisite files that are not in the current directory; however, make uses VPATH as a search list for both prerequisites and targets of rules.

Comment: V is for virtual, if anything.

Comment: My guess would be "variable" since it's a list of directories that can change to your specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VPATH seems to be: **virtual path**

I found this link about: [gcc_make](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html)

Which defines VPATH like this:

```
>**Virtual Path - VPATH & vpath**

>You can use VPATH (uppercase) to specify the directory to search for dependencies and target files. For example,

># Search for dependencies and targets from "src" and "include" directories
># The directories are separated by space
```

VPATH = src include

```
>You can also use vpath (lowercase) to be more precise about the file type and its search directory. For example,

># Search for .c files in "src" directory; .h files in "include" directory
># The pattern matching character '%' matches filename without the extension
>vpath %.c src
>vpath %.h include
```

This [**second link**](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/make.html) confirm that:

> VPATH stands for Virtual path